# In App Purchases SKProductsResponse is empty only in iOS 6

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, skproduct

I have In-App purchases implemented for auto-renewable subscriptions and they are running absolutely fine in iOS7. All from loading of products to payment transactions, everything is great. 
But when I run my application on iOS6  the `didReceiveResponse` method returns an empty `response.products` and the product id is listed in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`. 
My code is as simple as:

```
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:set];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

where `set` is the NSMutableSet with product ids.

Everything is running absolutely fine in iOS7 but not in iOS6. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the device with iOS6 was jailbroken. I removed AppSync from Cydia and then the IAP worked fine.